# Elasticsearch - Recursive nested JSON object

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I'm trying to parse an HTML document into nested set of tags and content. It needs to support arbitrary nesting depth. The object (created in 
Python code) looks like:

```
{
  "content": [
    "some text about a thing, ",
  {"content": "More text with additional set of tags ",
  "tags": ["strong"]
  }
  ], 
  "tags": ["p"]
}
```

ES seems to dislike this structure, because the `content` field is of both a text and object type, producing this error; `"reason": "mapper [content] of different type, current_type [text], merged_type [ObjectMapper]"`

Does anyone have any ideas on how to index this type of object, and also allow for searches on both tags and content? Ideally I'd like to search by tags associated with the ancestors of a given object too. I can reformat it to

```
{
  "content": [
  {"content": "some text about a thing, "},
  {"content": "More text with a different set of tags ",
  "tags": ["strong"]
  }
  ], 
  "tags": ["p"]
}
```

But then searching isn't very effective as I need to write content.content:"search string" to get results, which will become hard with multiple levels of nesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not store the ancestor tags in a separate field? Implementing a nested set will should solve your problem too.

Edit: As requested here comes a example of a nested set

Imagine a tree structure. Every node in this tree has a set of properties like description, or other attributes. Each node holds also a reference to it's parent node. Beside this there are two numbers: left and right position in the tree when traversing with in-depth search:

```
A(parent:null, left:1, right:12, desc:“root node“)
B(parent:A, left:2, right:3, desc:“left child“)
C(parent:A, left:4, right:11, desc:“right child“)
D(parent:C, left:5, right:6, desc:“foo“)
E(parent:C, left:7, right:10, desc:“bar“)
F(parent:E, left:8, right:9, desc:“baz“)
```

Calculating all ancenstors of a node is now easy:

ancestors(F for X) = search nodes as N WHERE N.left < X.left AND N.right > X.right

For the node F you'll get [E,C,A]. Ordering them by the left value you'll get the proper order for the ancestors of F.

So now you can use this criteria for the filter query in ES and use a second query for the search in the attributes of filtered nodes.

This structure is very efficient when looking for subtrees, but has  downsides when you change the node order/position.

If you need further explanation, please add a comment.

Comment: I'm not sure if that solves the problem, as it doesn't appear to allow me to search a document by its ancestor content? Also, I'm not sure if it solves the issue with not knowing how deep to nest content.content when searching.

Comment: Maybe if you can provide some example data (and a mapping if the correct one is not created automatically) I'll understand a bit better. At the moment I can't actually find any reference to nested sets on the ES documentation.

Comment: Please see the extended answer above.

Comment: I was hoping to use some of the ES nested mapping features to make this a bit easier (i.e. avoid manual creation of left/right ordering fields in Python, unless this can be done using an ES analyser somehow?). This almost looks like it would suit a parent/child relation better than a nested mapping? I do think it would probably work, so will accept as answer if no better options pop up. Changing the ordering etc. of nodes isn't a major issue as I'm happy to fully re-create a document.

Comment: Because of your recursive structure of html tags (without a known depth) you'll have no luck with your approach. And even if you would make it somehow work (help from the dark side or some vodoo) you'll get an structure impossible to query/search. Give the nested set a try and I promise, you'll be happy of the ease of this approach. Cheers!